# My WebAPI2 service returns a JSON string, but $resource does not parse it

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

Here is my resource:

```
var app, deps;

deps = ['ngGrid', 'getUsers'];

angular.module('getUsers', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('users', function ($resource)
  {
      return $resource('/Admin/GetUsers', {}, {
          query: { method: 'GET', IsArray: true }
      });
  });
```

and then I've added code to try to add a step to force parsing:

```
$scope.myData = users.query(function(response)
{
    if (typeof (response) == string)
    {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
    }
 });
```

But it never gets this far, and here's the error in Chrome:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$resource/badcfg?p0=array
    at http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:78:12
    at a.module.factory.f.(anonymous function).p.then.m.$resolved (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js:8:517)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:11046:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:11046:81)
    at http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:11132:26
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:12075:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:11903:31)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:12179:24)
    at done (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:7939:45)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:23002/Scripts/angular.js:8142:7)
```

Of course I searched for that error, but I found advice to set IsArray to true or false, this makes no difference.  If I set a breakpoint and call JSON.parse on the response string, it gets turned into an array of objects, exactly like what I want.  So the string is perfectly valid JSON, but angular appears unwilling to parse it as such, it accepts it as a string and then dies.

My controller is very simple:

```
    public List<ApplicationUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return AdminUsersViewModel.AllUsers;
    }
```

and then, that method uses a LINQ query to get users from the DB, and then iterates over that collection to create a new one, because before I did that, it just blew up.  I've made the call in the browser, and see the same string that is appearing in the angular code.

What I need to know is, why isn't angular spotting that this is a collection of objects, and how can I either force it to parse the string, or change the format so angular can tell what it is ?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.  I thought the help I read said to use IsArray ( in hindsight, I think it said DON'T use IsArray ).  I knew that was non standard, but that's what I did.  I ran the non minified version, and found my error.  Change to isArray, and it works.

Thanks for looking :-)